# Replacing file contents with SED in 2 files

Tags: text-processing, json

I have 2 files.

File 1 looks like this:

```
Company: "Acme CO"
Address: "123 Main Street"
Zip: "12345"
```

File 2 is a JSON file with variables as placeholders for this data.  For example, `%%company%%` where the company name will go.

I need to be able to search file 1 to get the values for company, address, zip etc, and replace the variables in file 2 with this data.

Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you show us the snippet of the JSON file? I suggest using Python to do JSON file manipulation

Comment: Sure! Here you go!

Comment: Sure! Here you go!
{
        "identifier": "%%id%%",
        "name": "%%company%%",
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
     "name": "Active",
     "_info": {

Comment: expected output in json file ? I am sure there will be array of records in json file.

Comment: Sagar, I'm actually just trying to replace contents in file 1, in the contents of file 2... Not really tying to create a new file, more just modify the existing with contents of another file...

Answer (score 1):

#### Run this:

```
 cat a.json | awk -v file="data.txt" -f substitude.awk
```

#### Where

substitude.awk

```
BEGIN{
    while(getline < file) {
            split($0, data, ":");
            key = "%%" tolower(data[1]) "%%";
            value = data[2];
            gsub(/^\s*\"|\"\s*$/, "", value)
            map[key] = value;
    }
}{
    s = $0;
    for(key in map) {
            gsub(key, map[key], s);  
    }
    print s;
}END{

}
```

data.txt:

```
Id: "123"
Company: "Acme CO"
Address: "123 Main Street"
Zip: "12345"
```

a.json:

```
{ "identifier": "%%id%%", "name": "%%company%%" }
```

#### Result

```
{ "identifier": "123", "name": "Acme CO" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nE  'if ($ARGV eq "f2" ){ say s/%%(.*?)%%/$d{$1}/gr } 
           elsif( /(\w+):\s*"(.*)"/ ){ $d{$1}=$2 }'    f1 f2
```